# How to determine $\lim_{t\to \infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-tx}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx$?

Tags: integration, limits

Let $f(t):=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-tx}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx$

I want to determine $\lim_{t\to \infty}f(t)$.

I guess I need to use dominated convergence theorem but in dominated convergence theorem there is always a sequence $(f_n)$ of functions so how does it work here?

Comment: $\sin(x)/x$ is bounded, so $|f(t)|\le\int_0^\infty \exp(-xt)~\mathrm dx=\cdots$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @SimplyBeautifulArt noted, for the DCT use $|\frac{\sin x}{x}|\le1\implies|e^{-tx}\frac{\sin x}{x}|\le e^{-tx}$. So the limit is $0$ by the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 1):

notice:
$$f(t)=\int_0^\infty e^{-tx}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx$$
$$f'(t)=-\int_0^\infty e^{-tx}\sin(x)dx$$
from this we can see that $f'(t)$ is always negative and decreasing, so as $t$ increases $f(t)$ decreases to a horizontal asymptote. also notice that:
$$\int_1^\infty e^{-tx}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx\le\int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-tx}}{x}dx=C-\ln(t)$$
and this is clearly convergent for any $t>0$

Comment: oh yes sorry, I meant that function over $(1,\infty)$. I have changed it now