Upper bound for a function
In a certain exercise I have been asked to find the following limit: $$\lim_{t \to \infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-tx} \frac{\sin x}{x}$$ using the Dominated Convergence Theorem. My attempt was the following:
$$ \lim_{t \to \infty} Integral = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t_nx}\frac{\sin x}{x}$$ for any sequence  $(t_n \to \infty)$. Then I define $g_n(x) = e^{-t_nx}\frac{\sin x}{x}$. These functions are obviously measurable (or mabye not so obvious?)  for a fixed $n$, but I struggle at finding a function that appears as an  upper boundary. I tried with $1$, but this is not Lebesgue-integrable in $(0,\infty) $ (the integral is infinite). Then I tried with $e^{-t_nx}$. This function has a finite integral and is always bigger than the original function, but the problem is that it depends on $n$, while the theorem states that the upper function need not depend on $n$. However, no matter which $n$ you take, the integral of the upper boundary is always finite, the problem is that in the expression of that function there is always something that depends on $n$. Which upper function should I take?

Note that $e^{-tx} \le e^{-x}$ for $t \ge 1$.

See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3388620/42969 for a simple solution which does not need the dominated convergence theorem.

I didn't mention in the post, but I'm given $t \geq 0$. I'm also required to use DTC. I can do it without it.

When you compute the limit for $t \to \infty$ then it suffices to consider $t \ge 1$.
